# Error Message "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile" while Executing Google Analytics API Code

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-api-php-client

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am currently working on implementing the Google Analytics API in PHP using the example code provided in this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php.

However, upon executing the code, I encountered the following error message:

```
{
  "error":{
    "code":403,
    "message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
    "errors":[
     {
        "message":"User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
        "domain":"global",
        "reason":"forbidden"
     }
    ],
    "status":"PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

It seems that my code is unable to access the necessary permissions for the Google Analytics profile. I have followed the steps provided in the documentation to set up the credentials and authentication properly, but I still face this issue.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this "PERMISSION_DENIED" error and successfully execute the code to fetch Google Analytics data.

I also leave my code and screenshots of the configuration that I have made

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/../application/vendor/autoload.php';

$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$response = getReport($analytics);
printResults($response);


/**
 * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 *
 * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 */
function initializeAnalytics()
{

    // Use the developers console and download your service account
    // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
    // change the key file location if necessary.
    $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/../application/avgeneral-0314e415c449.json';

    // Create and configure a new client object.
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
    $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
    $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
    $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

    return $analytics;
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics)
{

    // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
    $VIEW_ID = "123456789";//is other of course
    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("today");
    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");
    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));
    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests(array($request));
    try {
        $response = $analytics->reports->batchGet($body);
    } catch (Google\Service\Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $response;
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports)
{
    for ($reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count($reports); $reportIndex++) {
        $report = $reports[$reportIndex];
        $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
        $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
        $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
        $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

        for ($rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
            $row = $rows[$rowIndex];
            $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
            $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
                print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
                $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                    $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                    print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: *I have followed the steps provided in the documentation to set up the credentials and authentication properly* did you add permissions too?

Answer (score 0):

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile

means exactly that, the user doesnt have access to that account.

Go to the google analytics website under the admin section and add the service account as a user.

[image]

Comment: It has administrative permissions and even so it continues to give an error, attach a screenshot, it belongs to the property but it also has the same permission in the account.

Comment: Did you put it at the account level.  You know your using the UA analytics API right?  Your account looks like it may be a GA4 account.

Comment: I'm not really an expert, I'm just trying to port an app to GA4 that stopped working. Can you explain me better.

Comment: you need to use the google analytics data api if you want to extract data from a GA4 account.

Comment: And what am I supposed to be doing?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/analytics-data/latest  try using this